# What do the return values denote for GTIFWriteKeys and GTIFKeySet libgeotiff functions (C++)?

Tags: c++, geotiff

In the (partial) libgeotiff API [documentation](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/api/geotiff_8h.html#a3fa3e3e55cf8ddb6aa035b8f17a25f35), the meanings of the return values for the following functions are not stated:

- GTIFWriteKeys
- GTIFKeySet

What possible return values will these functions return? What do the values mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig through the source code to figure these out, and I am guessing that somebody else might benefit from this information. The simple answer is, that both of these functions will return 1 for success, and 0 for failure. This is straight forward, but because libtiff varies in what return values mean for various functions, I was unsure how libgeotiff would handle these.